# Ошибка Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS

Tags: sql, symfony, dql

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную ошибку в Symfony?

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 100: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '<'

Код репозитория, который ее вызывает:

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
/**
 * FacesRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class FacesRepository extends EntityRepository{

    public function findFacesOver(){

        return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery("SELECT f.full_name, ((YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(f.birth_date)) - (DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(f.birth_date, '%m%d'))) AS age FROM AcmeHelloBundle:Faces f WHERE (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(f.birth_date)) - (DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(f.birth_date, '%m%d')) > 27")
                ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот полный запрос: 
    
    public function findFacesOver(){
        
        return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery("SELECT f.full_name, ((YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(f.birth_date)) - (DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(f.birth_date, '%m%d'))) AS age FROM AcmeHelloBundle:Faces f WHERE (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(f.birth_date)) - (DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%m%d') < DATE_FORMAT(f.birth_date, '%m%d')) > 27")
                ->getResult();
    }

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, код у вас не отражает то, что написано в ошибке.

Во-вторых, в тексте самой ошибки явно указано, в чем проблема: предполагалось, что Вы закроете все открытые скобки в запросе, а Вы этого не сделали. Посчитайте количество открывающих скобочек и закрывающих: у вас 6 открывающих скобки и 4 закрывающих. То есть Вы допустили эту ошибку уже как минимум дважды.

Посмотрите внимательнее на свой запрос и поставьте недостающие скобки.